# Does Vivien sleep with Merlin in Tennyson's "Idylls of the King"?

Tags: poetry, literary-device, sexuality, alfred-tennyson, idylls-of-the-king

I am re-reading Tennyson's [*Idylls of the King*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/610/610-h/610-h.htm) after many years. His idyll "[Merlin and Vivien](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/610/610-h/610-h.htm#link2H_4_0007)" is a rather in-depth look at how Vivien learns Merlin's magic through some impressive feats of flattery.

Toward the end, we read thus (my emphasis):

> "O Merlin, though you do not love me, save,
> Yet save me!" clung to him and hugged him close;
> [...] she called him lord and liege,
> Her seer, her bard, her silver star of eve,
> **Her God, her Merlin, the one passionate love**
> Of her whole life; and ever overhead
> **Bellowed the tempest**, and the rotten branch
> Snapt in the **rushing of the river-rain**
> Above them; and in change of glare and gloom
> Her eyes and neck glittering **went and came**;
> **Till now the storm, its burst of passion spent**,
> Moaning and calling out of other lands,
> Had left the ravaged woodland yet once more
> To peace; and what should not have been had been,
> For Merlin, overtalked and overworn,
> Had yielded, told her all the charm, and **slept**.

This passage feels like there is much more happening than a simple social engineering attempt in a rainstorm. Rather, the imagery seems consistent with Vivien bringing Merlin to sexual climax - the imagery of rushing, coming, and sleeping afterwards.

Is this a reasonable interpretation of the passage, or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't believe Merlin and Viviene have sex. He 'yields', yes, but not in that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your interpretation is a common way to understand this passage. Mid-Victorian literary conventions required some delicacy in alluding to sexual activity, so this kind of suggestive imagery is all we would normally expect to find. Here are a couple of other readers taking it this way:

> Tennyson makes it clear that they indulged their passions during this “storm”
>
> <sub>Kristina Pérez (2014). [*The Myth of Morgan La Fey*, p. 165](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1057/9781137332981). Palgrave Macmillan.</sub>

> The storm here is obviously a metaphor for sex, “its burst of passion” is “spent,” it is “moaning and calling out” and the forest is “ravaged” by the storm’s passions.
>
> <sub>Sarah Curtis (2015). [*Revealing Influence: Exploring British Identity, Sexual Power, and Lyric Ambiguity in Spenser, Keats, And Tennyson*, p. 67](https://www.proquest.com/openview/3983f3a2172861506b3bfd00665c0621/1). Southern Illinois University Carbondale.</sub>

The literary device is “[pathetic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathetic_fallacy)”, that is, the displacement of the characters’ emotions to the weather.

In using a storm in “Merlin and Vivien”, Tennyson may have been thinking of the episode in book IV of the *Aeneid*, in which the goddess Juno summons a storm to force Dido and Aeneas to take refuge in a cave, and [Virgil writes](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0054%3Abook%3D4%3Acard%3D160), “the flash of lightnings on the conscious air
were torches to the bridal; from the hills the wailing wood-nymphs sobbed a wedding song.”

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful to know that my literature analysis skills have gotten better. When I first read this as a teen, I envisioned Vivien just standing there soaked while begging to be taught magic.